# Exception while starting up the server : java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>()

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have implemented UserDetailsService from Spring and created a function for getting the user from database, while starting up the server I'm getting the following error

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:787)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:434)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:779)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:284)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1322)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:731)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:563)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:359)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:787)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:434)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:779)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:284)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1322)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:731)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:563)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:359)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2015-08-15 23:43:53.155:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
2015-08-15 23:43:53.171:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started     ServerConnector@cf88935{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

Following contains my spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/login"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/admin"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/**"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/app/login"
        default-target-url="/app/base/" always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/app/login?error=true" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/app/logout" />
    <security:access-denied-handler
        error-page="/app/User/error/403" />
</security:http>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5"></security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I have used these libraries:

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this the implementation of UserDetailsService

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDao")
UserDao userDao;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userService")
UserService userService;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    User user = userService.findUserByUsername(username);
    if (user != null) {
        String password = user.getPassword();
        boolean enabled = user.getActive();
        boolean accountNonExpired = user.getActive();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = user.getActive();
        boolean accountNonLocked = user.getActive();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (Role r : user.getRoles()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.getAuthority()));
        }
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User securedUser = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        return securedUser;
    } else {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                "Unable to find user with username provided!!");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ProviderManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html) in **Spring 4** doesn't have default constructor anymore, so it could not be created with your xml configuration.

Provider manager configuration in Spring 4 must look like:

```
<bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

see: [spring-security migration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help, server has started. Replaced the previous code with `<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
  <constructor-arg>
   <list>
    <ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
   </list>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>`